# How can I add a new Id to the web elements in a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, ruby, testing, cucumber, watir

I am testing an application that uses the `Ruby` and `Cucumber` frameworks and there are many JavaScript files that describe: every action in the application, every element's: `ID`, `Class`, `Name`, etc. As a tester, I want to go through the JavaScript files to add unique IDs to every element; I have to capture (`data-test-id`), so that I have a stable test case, which does not break with new builds.

I am not very familiar with JavaScript and would like to get some help with respect to the best way to make the changes I have described, particularly about how to identify where I must add/change the element `ID`?

Comment: Perhaps you need to share the JavaScript file that you want to modify? I'm not sure that we can answer how to change it without knowing what we are changing. That said, I do no understand why you need to modify the JavaScript files. It sounds like an unusual practice. Watir should be used to interact with the browser as a user would.

Comment: @JustinKo I think the OP wants to modify the application to add unique IDs to elements, in order to make the tests easier to write and more stable.  srinivas, am I correct?

Comment: @Wayne Conrad u cannot be more correct :P thanks !!! i want to add data-test-id to every element before i use it in my testing script, so i have more stable builds in the long run. can you guide me through how to do that

Comment: Sadly I cannot guide you, for two reasons: I am not an expert at Ruby web programming, but also you've shown no code.  Without any code or other context, I think we would have to give too broad of an answer.